# PIRCBOT - How to add voice to all users in the channel - Java

Tags: java, irc

I'm using the pircbot to make an IRC bot. How do I make the bot add voice to all the users in the channel? Or when the users join?

Comment: Try **[JawaBot 2.x](http://code.google.com/p/jawabot/)** which has an AutoOp plugin. To get "AutoVoice" is a 2 lines change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably something like this:

```
import org.jibble.pircbot.*;

public class MyBot extends PircBot {

  public MyBot() {
    this.setName("MyBot");
  }

  public void onJoin(String channel, String sender,
                   String login, String hostname, String message) {
    this.voice(channel, sender);
  }

  public void voiceAll(String channel) {
    int i = 0;
    User[] users = this.getUsers(channel);
    while (i < users.length)
      this.voice(channel, users[i++].getNick());
  }
}

public class MyBotMain {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    MyBot bot = new MyBot();
    bot.connect("irc.freenode.net");
    bot.joinChannel("#chan");
    bot.voiceAll("#chan"); 
  }

}
```

You should verify some stuff before voicing (are you in the chan? are you operator?).
Take a look at the API page: http://www.jibble.org/javadocs/pircbot/index.html.

Comment: Is Users[] ment to be User[] ? As eclipse throws up an exception otherwise.